# How to prevent go mod tidy from looking up a replaced module path

Tags: go, go-modules

Consider the following setup:

---

`go.mod`

```
module example.com/main

require example.com/sub dummy
replace example.com/sub => ./sub
```

---

`sub/go.mod`

```
module example.com/sub
```

---

If I run `go mod tidy` in the main directory, it emits

```
go: errors parsing go.mod:
[…]/go.mod:3: unrecognized import path "example.com/sub": reading https://example.com/sub?go-get=1: 404 Not Found
```

Even if the URL existed, my understanding is that due to the `replace` directive, `go mod` has no business whatsoever with the original source because I replaced it. So why is it querying the source then? And how can I prevent that?

I already tried to set `GOPROXY=off` which resulted in

```
[…]/go.mod:3: module lookup disabled by GOPROXY=off
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign a proper version number like `v0.0.0` and it will work.

Go modules use the semantic versioning model and cannot have arbitrary versions like `dummy`. The supported version formats are described in [Module version numbering](https://go.dev/doc/modules/version-numbers).

---

Bonus note: avoid nesting Go modules. That may lead to a messy setup and problems with tooling down the road.

Comment: Ah yes, I remember reading that `go mod` will try to replace a non-canonical version but I didn't think that would take precedence over `replace`. This fix works, thanks! btw the modules are only nested here for demonstration, the actual replace path goes into the nix store.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at [`go mod tidy`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Add_missing_and_remove_unused_modules), try first ([Go 1.16+](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy), from [issue 26603](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26603)):

```
go mod tidy -e
```

> The `-e` flag makes `tidy` attempt to proceed despite errors encountered while loading packages.

Comment: Doing this on `go1.16.12` gives the same error and still does not write `go.sum` (the point of why I run `go mod tidy`) and also has a non-zero exit code.

Comment: @flyx Would that persist with go 1.17.5, or 1.18 beta 1?

Comment: `go1.17.5` gives the same error, I don't have quick access to 1.18.